# How do I use vim as a hex editor on OSX?

Tags: macos, vim, editor, hex

I have tried using `:Hexmode` and `:%!xxd` but to no avail. Also tried opening vim with `-b` flag and then using `:setlocal display=uhex`.

The `:%!xxd` did nothing (claimed illegal)
`:Hexmode` just left everything as is and didn't change my inserted keys to hex characters. Same for `:setlocal display=uhex`.

Tried on file type: "ASCII C++ program text"

Comment: What worked? What didn't? What files di you try it with?

Answer (score 2):

`:%!xxd` is just telling vim to filter the current file through the separate `xxd` program and read the results back in.

I suspect that either you don't have a version of `xxd` installed in OSX (although [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xxd.1.html) suggests that it should indeed be present), or you **haven't saved the file you're trying to convert**. What happens if you run `xxd` in a terminal. Here's an example of what you get in a command window on Windows:

```
C:\>xxd
12345
^Z
0000000: 3132 3334 350d 0a                        12345..
```

i.e. I ran `xxd`, typed <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> and pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>, and the `xxd` program converted this as shown.